# Build Android Fail when using cordova-plugin-mfp-push

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

Plugin Version : 8.0.2021062405

When ever i run ionic  cordova build android with cordova-plugin-mfp-push plguin installed i am getting the below error mentioned.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\anis.khalfaoui\Desktop\ProxymProjects\kgoc-frontend\platforms\android\app\build.gradle' line: 102

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration 'classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:+.
     Required by:
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified
      > Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.            > Could not get resource 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.        
               > Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 15s
C:\Users\anis.khalfaoui\Desktop\ProxymProjects\kgoc-frontend\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.        

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

this is the line 102 in Build file 'C:\Users\anis.khalfaoui\Desktop\ProxymProjects\kgoc-frontend\platforms\android\app\build.gradle'

```
apply from: "../cordova-plugin-mfp-push/ibm-build-extras.gradle"
```

Answer (score 0):

As you see in error message, you have provided + for `com.android.tools.build:gradle` version in build.gradle file.
Please provide complete version like `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0`.

That should resolve your issue.

Thanks

Comment: didn't resolve my issue and i have updated the question please take a look